# Perl: How to pass ARGV parameters to another script?

Tags: perl, parameters, system, call, argv

I wrote a Perl script that launches another program and I want it to pass the exact ARGV parameters it received to the launched program.

Currently I use this code:

```
my $cmd = "script.sh"
my $params_str = "";
foreach my $param (@ARGV) {
        $params_str .= " $param";
}

$cmd .= " " . $params_str;
system($cmd);
```

But I am afraid that the following scenario will be problematic:

```
>perl script.pl "param with spaces" param2 param3
```

As it will call my `$cmd` with the first parameter separated into 3 parameters, as the quotation marks would be removed: `param with spaces param2 param3`

Is there an elegant way to pass the parameters correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) can be used with list of parameters,

```
system("script.sh", @ARGV);
```

which is also preferable way of `system` usage, and you don't have to worry about 
`"param with spaces"`.